# SQL Server : can not connect?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using IIS with latest PHP and SQL Server 2017.

Since this code is old and I want to upgrade to

```
<?php
function Conectarse()
{
global $link;
if (!($link=mssql_connect("xxxxxxxxxx","sa","1234")))
{
exit();
}
if (!mssql_select_db("UserLogin",$link))
{
exit();
}
return $link;
}
Conectarse();

$AccDir = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$NameServer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$xxxxxxxWebLink = "http://xxxxxxx.com//";
$xxxxxxxForumLink = "http://xxxxxxxx.com/";
$SupportLink = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/";

//data for emails
$SMTPUser = "xxxxxxxxx"; //GMail user or POP3 account
$SMTPPass = ""; //Password
$SMTPEmail = "xxxxxxxxx"; //Sender Email
$SMTPName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Sender's Name

// Maintenance Mode On / Off
$config = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM ServerConfig");
$config1 = mssql_fetch_array($config);
$config2 = $config1[0];
if($config2 == '1'){ $Mantenimiento = "On"; } else { $Mantenimiento = "Off"; }

// Change of Office
$changecost = '16000'; //Cost of Change

?>
```

since the `mssql` is no more support, so I've searched but no luck, this is from config.php

and I got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxx\config\config.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxx\config\config.php(15): Conectarse()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxx\config\config.php on line 5
```

Comment: There is no **SQL Server 15** - what do you really mean? We have SQL Server 2005 (v9), 2008 (v10), 2008 R2 (v10.5), 2012 (v11), 2014 (v12), 2016 (v13) and 2017 (v14) - none of them has any "15" in its version number.....

Comment: sorry, its 2015 not 15, i was suggested to change some of my word in my post.

Comment: Again: there **is NO** SQL Server **2015** ....... I listed **all** valid versions in my first comment - take your pick!

Comment: "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17289.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.283
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.16299.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.16299"

Comment: Run `SELECT @@VERSION`  against your SQL Server -that'll tell you the version of the underlying SQL Server **database engine** (those are version numbers of all different management tools etc - not the core database engine.....)

Comment: my bad. it says  (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 16299: ))

Comment: There you go - SQL Server **2017** - I updated your question accordingly